# Windows taskbar height/width

Tags: java, taskbar

I can't figure out how to get the windows taskbar height dynamicaly to set my application fullscreen.
As you know, taskbar can be in four positions: bottom, top, left or right, so I'm wondering if it's possible to also know the current position to set the window bounds.

EDIT:
Using Lukas link I tryied this:

```
GraphicsDevice myDevice;
Window myWindow;

try {
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(myWindow);
    ...
} finally {
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
```

But I'm gettin a `NullPointerException`

Comment: yes sorry, I'm using a JFrame

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create your `JFrame`. Make a call to the `setExtendedState()` method in the JFrame API

```
jFrame = new JFrame("TESTER");
jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

The MAXIMIZED_BOTH setting will set your window to fullscreen and automatically take into account the position of the Taskbar.

Comment: This could be a solution, but I was hoping for a toggle-method to set the JFrame fullscreen and go back to "normal" size.

Comment: You could set a default size like `jFrame.setSize(450,450)` and then call `jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` when you press the maximize button on the top of the window it will toggle between the two sizes.

Comment: is there a way to toggle between max and normal with a button?

Comment: NOTE: this will not work when using a swing "LookAndFeel" decorated window.  It will cover the taskbar, So in this case as a work around for the bug in Java one has to know where the taskbar is to size the window accordingly. Really annoying !!!

Comment: @peterk This is from almost a year ago

Answer (score 26):

It is possible to obtain the Windows taskbar height if necessary:

```
Dimension scrnSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Rectangle winSize = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();

int taskBarHeight = scrnSize.height - winSize.height;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
int taskbarheight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height 
    - GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height();
```

or you can use, as well:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().getSize();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your Application to run in full-screen mode, you can enter it by getting a suitable [`GraphicsDevice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) and using the [`setFullScreenWindow(Window)`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow%28java.awt.Window%29):

```
GraphicsDevice myDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.
   getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
Window myWindow;

try {
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(myWindow);
    ...
} finally {
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
```

For further (and more complete) information. see the [Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html))

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a program I wrote:

```
public enum Location {
    TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT;
}

private static final class Taskbar {
    public final Location location;
    public final int width, height;

    private Taskbar(Location location, int width, int height) {
        this.location = location;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public static Taskbar getTaskbar() {
        Rectangle other = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getMaximumWindowBounds();
        return new Taskbar(other.x != 0 ? Location.TOP
                : (other.y != 0 ? Location.LEFT
                        : (other.width == IFrame.width ? Location.BOTTOM
                                : Location.RIGHT)), IFrame.width
                - other.width, IFrame.height - other.height);
    }
}
```

Essentially, calling `Taskbar.getTaskbar()` will give a taskbar containing information on its location (`TOP`, `RIGHT`, `BOTTOM`, `LEFT`), its width, and its height.